# How to get Spring Boot to map query parameters separately from form data?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, form-data, query-string

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object mirror(HttpServletRequest req, @Nullable @RequestBody Map<String, String> form) {
      ...
    }
```

I just want the plain key and value for all form data entries here but it also includes query parameters in the map.

I need to be able to tell the difference between what came from the form and what came from the query.

Getting the query parameters separately is easily done using URI parsing but it's not so easy to remove the query parameters from the form map. Especially in the case they have the same keys.

Changing the parameter to MultiValueMap adds values with the same key into an array. Using just a Map causes the query parameters to overwrite the form data with equal keys.

I found where this is happening, for the MockHttpServletRequest at least: `buildRequest` method:

```
        String query = this.url.getRawQuery();
        if (!this.queryParams.isEmpty()) {
            String s = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().queryParams(this.queryParams).build().encode().getQuery();
            query = StringUtils.isEmpty(query) ? s : query + "&" + s;
        }
        if (query != null) {
            request.setQueryString(query);
        }
        addRequestParams(request, UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(this.url).build().getQueryParams());

        this.parameters.forEach((name, values) -> {
            for (String value : values) {
                request.addParameter(name, value);
            }
        });
```

It's combining the form data and query data into one map. So is there an alternative way to parse the form data ONLY or exclude query params from the map!?

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc for `@RequestParam`:

> In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API combines query parameters and form data into a single map called "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.

Not sure if there's a more elegant way, but you could possibly use Spring's `UriComponentsBuilder` class to parse the URI string and get back the query parameters.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can get the query parameters separately, the problem is getting the form data separately.

Comment: Have you tried using `@RequestParam` together with `@RequestBody`?

Comment: Yes, body is null

Comment: When I try `@Nullable @RequestBody Object body`, body == null. Without @Nullable I get a 404 because Spring can't find a controller that accepts a null body.

Comment: There must be a way to JUST get the form data... I can't find any way to get it from the `HttpServletRequest` that doesn't include query parameters

Comment: Agree, all the docs for `@RequestBody` make no mention of consuming the query params with it, but could be related to how servlet is combining everything. Might also be worth playing with the accept type (i.e. using form encoded vs. all).

Comment: Problem here is I'm building a proxy which just needs to accept any incoming request, forward it to the real host, get the response and return it, doing a little parsing/stat monitoring in between. Works great until you add URL params on top of form data. The URL params are being sent in the outgoing request which breaks some API's... I'm getting somewhere by wrapping the original `Request` object via `HttpFilter`